# Open Saveas dialog in angularjs 1.2 (or javascript) and HTML 4x

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, download, window

I am AJAX call and when the server (REST service) sends the response it is actually a link to the generated file something like

```
/project/tmporaryFiles/file.abc
```

(File extension is also customized) It is just a text file. when I use `$window.open` then it just opens the text file in the browser and displays the text. I would like to open a saveas dialog box so that user user should be able to save the file instead of viewing it in the browser. I have tried multiple threads of stackoverflow but could not found solution. Most of the solutions are for HTML5 i.e. the download attribute in anchor, I believe this is not available in HTML4x.
One solution I am trying to find is to create a Blob with the response link but that I am unable to do.

Also note the file can be more than 100MB as well based on the data processing and input by the user.

Answer (score 1):

I you want to force the download without using HTML5 `download` attribute, you will need to set [Content-Disposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition) on response header.

This can be done on server side and not client.

Comment: Yes it can be done, but my current issue is it is just a SIMPLE file on server which will be downloading so no inbetween server side coding is involved. its like when u press Save Target As in your browser. Can we do Save Target As thing programmatically in javascript?

Comment: Thanks Yaser, I did on server side by using a customized filter on the file extensions which required to be downloaded. Now whenever that SIMPLE file is accessed HeaderFilter will put content-disposition in the header of the response.